# How to get the fields with checkbox tick in django(Boolean Field)

Tags: python, django, forms, orm

My template: I want to get the data which are tick marked and then render it to other view.

```
 <form class="hero-menu">
                    {% for test in test %}
                    <div class="category-block">
                      <ul class="dropdown-list">
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><h4 data-modal-target="menu-test-popup">
                              {{test.name|title}}
                            </h4></a>
                        </li>
                        {% for subtest in test.subtest.all %}
                        <!-- {% if subtest.test_id == test.id %}   -->
                           <li>
                            <div class="checkbox-group">
                              <input type="checkbox" id="aUniqueName" name={{subtest.name}}
                              value="example"/>
                              <label for="aUniqueName">
                               {{subtest.name|title}}
                              </label>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                          <!-- {% endif %}  -->
                        {% endfor %}


                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}


                    <button class="button">Generate Report</button>
                  </form>
```

This is my models.In my models I have Test which has foreign key at subtest.

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Subtest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='subtest',blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    reference_value = models.IntegerField()
    selected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my view. I have used template_context_processor for my covinience.

```
def list_subtest(request):
return {'subtest':Subtest.objects.all(),'test':Test.objects.all().prefetch_related('subtest')}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I invite you to change from FBV to CBV, believe me it will positively change all the programming in Django.

I don't see your post method. I'll leave you here how I got it done:

**[template.html]**

```
<form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    {% for test in tests %}
        {% for subtest in subtests %}
            <input type="hidden" name="test_id" value="{{test.id}}">
            {% if test.id == subtest.test_id && subtest.selected %}
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{subtest.id}}" checked>{{subtest.name}}
                </label>
            {% else %}
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{subtest.id}}">{{subtest.name}}
                </label>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    ...

    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="GENERATE REPORT">
</form>
```

**[views.py]**

```
from .models import (
    Subtest,
    Test,
)
from django.views.generic import ListView

class ListSubsets(ListView):

    context_object_name = 'tests' # This replace context['tests']
    model = Test
    paginate_by = 1
    template_name = 'core/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListSubsets, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['subtests'] = Subtest.objects.all()
        # context['tests'] = Test.objects.all() # Without prefetch_related
        return context

    def post(self, request):
        post_dict = request.POST.dict()
        # test = Test.objects.get(id = post_dict['test_id'])
        subtests = Subtest.objects.all()
        for subtest in subtests:
            try:
                if str(subtest.test_id) in post_dict:
                    update = Subtest.objects.get(test = subtest.test_id)
                    update.selected = True
                    update.save()
            except:
                print("Doesn't exist.")
        return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

There are more subtle ways to do it, other more efficient ways, but the really right thing should be JavaScript. Test angle, I invite you, and please switch to CBV.

-------------------------------- o --------------------------------

**[settings.py]**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                # Our context processor for every app.
                # Core.
                'apps.functions.processor.cntxt_prcssr_templates_core',
           ],
        },
    },
]
```

**[processor.py]**

```
from .models import (
    Test,
    Subtest
)

# tests = Test.objects.all()
# subtests = Subtest.objects.all()

def cntxt_prcssr_templates_core(request=None):

    # TEST.
    'tests':       Test.objects.all(),
    # 'tests':       tests,

    # SUBTEST
    'subtests':    Subtest.objects.all(),
    # 'subtests':    subtests,

    return cntxt_templates_core
```

Then you only access tests, or subtests from any template. (html)

Comment: I want a template context processor. How can I do it with CBV??

Comment: Friend, first of all, thank you for take attention to the answer, your question is too badly formulated.
Second, context processor has nothing to do with FBV and CBV.
Third, why do you want to use context processor in this, do you understand what context processor means?
A context processor helps you to leave global variables across the templates (either text, values, etc), but how do you associate a CP with your form?
Why do you have a test field Boolean in subtest?

Comment: On the other hand, a Test should have Subtests. Not a subtest should contain a Test. You have everything really badly formulated.
I invite you to take another look at the issue, and learn more about how to set up a Foreign Key and especially a form.

Comment: I have used javascript and I don't want to change my urls. I just have a popup form . So that is why I have used template_context_processor . Can you please help me out . I don't want to add url to my view .

Comment: I do have subtest inside my test . That part has not been much of issue for me .And Thank you for your gesture

Comment: Think of it this way, I can have a car of many colors. I don't have a lot of car-type colors... both situations may be acceptable, but they are not correct.
Rethink your structure.
Regarding the rest, the context processor has nothing to do with what you want to do, it's just a global dictionary, so you can access those keys from any template.

Comment: Now understanding you better, if you really want to serialize your whole model and use it as a dictionary from your template referencing a context processor. I will edit my answer, but I insist that it is a little absurd. There is no need to build an urls if you reference the view or def.